# FOSUserBundle Change Login Form Names

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm currenlty developing a Symfony project, and I'm using the FOSUserBundle. I'm customizing the login page, and my question is, can I change login form names that need to be passed to /login_check? They suppose to be *_username* and *_password*, but can I change them to anything else? So, where do I need to configure that?

Thanks a lot,
Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your security.yml you can set the username and password parameters for each firewall.

This is taken from the [SecurityBundle Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html).

```
firewalls:            # Required
    # Examples:
    somename:
        form_login:
            # field names for the username and password fields
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
```